# Change from text to span in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like the a tag to change to span when the variable 'nav' is false. When I try to do this, the text literally changes to " home " and I wish it would become an icon. What can I do?

```
<a href="/">{nav ? 'HOME' : "<span class="material-symbols-outlined"> home </span>"}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `" "`

```
<a href="/">{nav ? 'HOME' : <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> home </span>}</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe move the code inside the class property and return an empty string when nav is true and `material-symbols-outlined` when its false.
Like this :

```
<a href="/"><span class={nav ? "" : "material-symbols-outlined"}>Home</span></a>
```

Comment: How would I do that? Can you send the code?